# for over list with different lengths in lapply

Tags: r

I have complicated function which includes many lists with different lengths. I would like to pass the same function over these lists using `lapply` but I got `NULL`. I know my problem but do not know how to fix it.

My first problem is here:

`AFA <- lapply(1:m, function(i) A[[i]][AA[[i]]])`

AFA is a list of two elements. Each element of list contains 10 elements.

`FA <-  lapply(1:m, function(i) { which(AFA[[i]][[j]] %in% c(2, 7))})`

FA tried to see which elements of the 10 elements are 2 or 7.

I know that `lapply` here is not help. But I could not use `mapply` in this case.

My second problem is:

```
`lapply(nAA2, function(x) if (x > 0) { ##if the length of the function is not zero.

      for(j in 1:m){
        for (i in 1:x) ....`
```

`nAA2` is a list of two elements. The length of the first element is `1` while `2` for the second element. Hence, the code says this:

for the length of the first element. `if (AFA[[j]][[FA[[i]]]] == 2)` this means, check each element of `AFA` using `FA` and since `FA` is also a list then I used `FA[[i]]`.

Instead to say:

`for ( i in 1:length(nAA2[[1]]) ....`
and 
`for ( i in 1:length(nAA2[[2]]) ....`

I would like to merge then in one code.

Here is my full code with my comments explaining the code lines:

```
A1 <- c(0, 2, 3, 4, 4,
        0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
A1  <- matrix(A1, 5, 5)
A2 <- c(0, 2, 3, 2, 4,
        0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
A2  <- matrix(A2, 5, 5)

A <- list(A1, A2)
m <- length(A)

AA <- lapply(A, function(x) x > 0)
AA2 <- lapply(A, function(x) x %in% c(2, 7))

AA[is.na(AA)] <- FALSE
AA2[is.na(AA2)] <- FALSE

nAA <- lapply(AA, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
nAA2 <- lapply(AA2, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

AFA <- lapply(1:m, function(i) A[[i]][AA[[i]]])
llA <- lapply(1:m, function(i) double(nAA[[i]]+nAA2[[i]]))
luA <- lapply(1:m, function(i) double(nAA[[i]]+nAA2[[i]]))
FA <-  lapply(1:m, function(i) { which(AFA[[i]][[j]] %in% c(2, 7))}) ## here 
AFA is a list of two elements. I would like to access the first element of 
the list,  and then check each element. I know this is wrong, but how to fix 
it with `mapply`. 


for(j in 1:m){

}
lapply(nAA2, function(x) if (x > 0) { ##here to check that they are not zero. That is we have number equal to 2 or 7.

  for(j in 1:m){ 
    for (i in 1:x) { #here I wouldl like to loop over the length of the 
    first list and then the second list.
      if (AFA[[j]][[FA[[i]]]] == 2) {
        # t
        llA[[j]][nAA[[i]] + i] <- 2
        luA[[j]][nAA[[i]] + i] <- 5 
      }
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
[[1]][[1]]
2
[[1]][[2]]
2


[[2]][[1]]
5
[[2]][[2]]
5
```

Comment: This is all a bit cryptic, could you show your expected output?

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks a lot. How about the second problem. I edit my question to make it so clear.

Comment: Can you explain the indexing within your for-loop? How do the positions within `AFA`, `FA`, `llA` and `luA` fit together? I'm pretty sure there's an easier solution to this, but I don't understand how you want to index the cells that should be changed.

Comment: Explain it this way: You check which elements within the vectors of list `AFA` are 2 (`if (AFA[[j]][[FA[[i]]]] == 2)`), but which elements within lists `llA` and `luA` should be changed? As I see it, `AFA` has two vectors each of length 10, but `llA` and `luA` each have two vectors of length 11 and 12.

Comment: I update my question for the second problem.

Comment: You are very close to my problem. `llA` and `luA` is a list with 10 elements all are zeros. The position of the element will changed to the number that I set.

Comment: For example the first element of the first list will be changed from zero to 2 and 5. For the second element, the first and third elements will be changed. However, the output for `luA` and `llA` will only display these elements (not all the 10 elements).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157052/discussion-between-lap-and-alice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer (only first problem):

> FA <-  lapply(1:m, function(i) { which(AFA[[i]][[j]] %in% c(2, 7))})
>
> FA tried to see which elements of the 10 elements are 2 or 7.

I think you are using `lapply` the wrong way. `lapply` loops over every object in a list, so to identify the vector elements which are either 2 or 7, just use

```
FA <-  lapply(AFA, function(x) which(x %in% c(2, 7)))

> FA
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 3
```

The output shows you the positions of vector elements that are either 2 or 7 in the both vectors of list `AFA`.

Solution for problem 2:

To be able to perform multiple tests and assign the corresponding values wo `luA` and `llA`, we first create new lists/vectors.

An example:

```
testvalues <- list(2, c(7, 10), c(3, 5))
llAvalues <- c(2, 1, 3)
luAvalues <- c(5, 2, 4)
```

These include the values to be tested for in `testvalues`, and the values to be given to `llA` and `luA` for the corresponding tests. The new objects must have the same lengths!

Now we use a nested `mapply` call to loop through `AFA` on the outer level, and through each test on the inner level.

```
llA <- mapply(function(v, w) mapply(function(x,y) ifelse(v[w] %in% x, y, 0), testvalues, llAvalues), AFA, FA)
luA <- mapply(function(v, w) mapply(function(x,y) ifelse(v[w] %in% x, y, 0), testvalues, luAvalues), AFA, FA)
```

Afterwards, we delete all generated `0` (could also use `NA`).

```
llA <- lapply(llA, function(x) x[x != 0])
```

which leaves us with the desired output.

Comment: for the second problem. I would like to loop over the length of each element of each list separately. The length of first and do all the job then run for the second element. For example, the first element has length 1 where the second element has length 2.

Comment: I hope that you can help me then, I can accept your answer.

Comment: Wait with accepting, your questions have not been answered fully. I still struggle to understand your second problem.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you. It is really an amazing help.